# message and title are not moving into Firebase DB

Tags: php, firebase, curl, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was writing a PHP Curl Code to send data from website to Firebase.

But It's is not saving in Firebase Database.

I had wrote below code for that ....

```
<?php 
$message = 'msg_1';
$title = 'title_1';
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$server_key = 'SERVER_KEY';

$key = 'db_key';

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization:key ='. $server_key,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$fields = array
(
    'to' => $key,
    'users'=>array
    (
        'username' => $title,
        'message' => $message
    )
);

$payload = json_encode($fields);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;

?>
```

It response me below line
    {"multicast_id":5950089806102679843,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

[My FireBase DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPXMF.png)

Kindly tell me the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If saved to a firebase database, write this.

```
<?php
// Constants
$FIREBASE = "_YOUR_FIREBASE_URL_";
$NODE_SAVE = "users.json";

$message = 'msg_1';
$title = 'title_1';

$data = array(
    'username' => $title,
    'message' => $message
);
// JSON encoded
$json = json_encode( $data );
// Initialize cURL
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $FIREBASE . $NODE_SAVE );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT" );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

// Close connection
$response = curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );
// Show result
echo $response . "\n";
?>
```

But your code. It means sending FCM.

> Do you want to send an FCM or firebase database record?

Comment: Thanks.
Sir, It's replacing the previous one. and also not saving as it should be save.

Comment: No problem, we are happy to help